# Why are "Computation result" and "Decimal approximation" so different?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am performing the following integral:

> SetPrecision[integrate(1*x^(1 - 1)*Exp[-x^1] *  log(1*x^(1 -
>   1)*Exp[-x^1]/((e^(-x) + 10*e^(-10*x))/2)), x= 0..infinity), 50]

When I do this on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SetPrecision%5Bintegrate%281*x%5E%281%20-%201%29*Exp%5B-x%5E1%5D%20*%20%20log%281*x%5E%281%20-%201%29*Exp%5B-x%5E1%5D%2F%28%28e%5E%28-x%29%20%2B%2010*e%5E%28-10*x%29%29%2F2%29%29%2C%20x%3D%200..infinity%29%2C%2050%5D) I get two results.

1. Computation result: SetPrecision[ integral_0^∞ x^(1 - 1) exp(-x^1) log((x^(1 - 1) exp(-x^1))/(1/2 (e^(-x) + 10 e^(-10 x)))) dx, 50] = 0.29085661088908043581113815889693796634674072265625
2. Decimal approximation: 0.290856610889057599214369459142912982430832330621859

I don't understand how the two numbers correspond to each other. Which is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Wolfram|Alpha are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @m_goldberg oh!  If the issue is identical in Mathematica would you reconsider?

Comment: Yes, if you rewrite your question, showing actual Mathematica code and the results it gives.

Comment: Consider using `WorkingPrecision` within `NIntegrate` to get a numerical result. Otherwise, once you remove the weird parts (e.g. `x^(1-1)` etc.), `Integrate[Exp[-x]*Log[Exp[-x]/((Exp[-x] + 10 Exp[-10 x])/2)], {x, 0, Infinity}]` returns an analytical result.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. Yes my example does look a little odd. The general version of that part is a Weibull density function.  I just simplified it as much as possible for the question by setting c=1 which makes it look strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "computational result" is obtained using `NIntegrate` with default `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` and `PrecisionGoal -> Automatic` (which usually is equivalent to `PrecisionGoal -> 6`):

```
cr = NIntegrate[Exp[-x]*Log[Exp[-x]/((Exp[-x] + 10 Exp[-10 x])/2)], {x, 0, Infinity}];
SetPrecision[cr, 50]
```

> ```
> 0.29085661088908043581113815889693796634674072265625`50.
> ```

So the integral is calculated using numerical methods with target precision of the result about 6 digits, and then you artificially set the precision of the result to be equal to 50. Hence all the digits after the 6'th digit are simply numerical junk.

The "decimal approximation" is obtained from the exact solution returned by `Integrate`:

```
an = Integrate[Exp[-x]*Log[Exp[-x]/((Exp[-x] + 10 Exp[-10 x])/2)], {x, 0, Infinity}]
SetPrecision[an, 50]
```

> ```
> 9 - 9 Hypergeometric2F1[1/9, 1, 10/9, -10] + Log[2] - Log[11]
>
> 0.2908566108890575992143694591429129824308323306218577972607`45.40436768400565 + 0``46.80171944058447 I
> ```

The "correct" (i.e. more precise) number is "decimal approximation".

Comment: Thanks so much. That is very helpful.